# Concurrency modes in WCF service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

Whenever I start the service, I load about 10,000 rows from the database and I want all my clients to access this data without bringing it back again, the outcomes of the threads for each client must be synchronized. I thought that (`InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;` and `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single;`) will work fine to me but the problem is that I want my concurrency mode to be Multiple to overcome the delay and make all the threads processed in parallel but I want to save the state and exchange data between threads coming from the same client after performing the thread. I read that I can use 'Lock' for that but if anyone can show me an example of how I can implement this I will be thankful.

Comment: You may use some `static` fields for shared data and switch to multiple instances.

Comment: You need to explain a little better what you need. For starters, please post your service contract definition, so we can get more context about what you are trying to do.